# Does parse pricing charge by plan or actual usage?

Tags: parse-platform

Let's say I buy 1000 req/s, but only use 30 req/s. Which do I get charged for? The docs are unclear to me "pro-rated by the hour." How can I spend the minimal amount while ensuring all requests fulfilled?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer-service request.

Comment: I disagree about closing this as enough developers utilize Parse in their apps that this seems like a relevant programming question, especially because their documentation still has some holes in it.

Comment: ^^logistical clarification; not customer service request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are charged by plan. If you take the 1000 req/s offer you will pay for 1000 req/s even if you only use 1.

The best way to handle that is to monitor the requests and change the plan when you get "too close" to the limit. I cannot give you a number or percentage as it heavily depends on your app. If your app evolves very slowly you can probably wait to reach 90%+ of the limit. On the other hand, If the app evolves very fast and you know you might get a lot of new users at any moments because your app is getting trending, you might want to be careful and start changing your plan at 50 or 60%. By default parse warns you when you reach 75%. At the end it's all about how your app is growing. You have an Analytics section in your app dashboard on Parse that will help you to monitor the requests and the growth of the app.